# How to validate Date object through io-ts (typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, runtime, typing

I haven't been able to find documentation on this, so here I am StackOverflow.

I have an interface that I want to convert and use in io-ts' run-time validation. This interface includes a field with type `Date` on it. I've looked through the rest of the commands on `t` when importing `io-ts` as `t` and I can't find a way to validate that it's a date

Ex:

```
export interface Transaction {
  transactionDate: Date,
  phrase: string
}
```

How do I convert this into a type using io-ts? Ideally it would be something like this

```
export const Transaction = t.type({
  transactionDate: t.date,
  phrase: t.string
})
```

The only thing that I've found that works is setting the Date as type `t.string`, but that would let any kind of string through.

Answer (score 3):

I found an npm package called `io-ts-types`. I was looking at the documentation thinking it was part of `io-ts` already.

https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts-types

There's a module built into `io-ts-types` dedicated to dates

https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts-types/modules/date.ts.html

Example of usage

```
import * as td from 'io-ts-types'

const dateObj = t.type({
  date: td.date
})

const test = {
  date: new Date()
}
```

You can use the decoder to validate that this works like so `isLeft(dateObj.decode(test))`